# How to put an image in React header

Tags: html, css, reactjs

How should you put an image on the left of the heading name?

```
 return (
    <div className="header">
      <img src={"/images/logo.png"} width="10" height="5" />
      <p className="name">heading name</p>
      <div className="header-right">
```

Comment: It isn't clear what the problem you have is. Is the image not appearing? Are you asking about the layout?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113481/make-an-image-and-a-paragraph-sit-next-to-each-other

Answer (score -1):

In your header class, which is basically a container for the `img, p and div`, add a grid.

```css
.header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 1fr 50px; // This will create 2 columns of 50 pixels, and the middle column will fill the remaining space  grid-template-rows: 1fr; // just one row
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```js
return (
    <div className="header">
      <img src={"/images/logo.png"} width="10" height="5" />
      <p className="name">heading name</p>
      <div className="header-right">
```